# How to play mediaItemCollection using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, mpmediaitemcollection

I think variable **mediaItemCollection** of func mediaPicker of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/displaying_a_media_picker_from_your_app have music files information I selected.

I would like to **play music files of mediaItemCollection** using **AVAudioPlayer**.